# Button onclick animation with sound and setting cookie

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

Ok, so I have this client that just NEEDS to have fancy animation when entering his site. Wordpress.
Thing is supposed to be a picture/button, that on click plays "engine" sound and reveals the main page.

I'm thinking about doing that in separate DIV that will just "vanish" when button is clicked and sound played. I checked around and I have some idea how to make that, but I have few questions.

1. what is the best way to achieve said effect? I'm thinking CSS3 + HTML5 + a bit of jquery is the way to go. But maybe there's something better. Example of getting sound on any element as on CSS Tricks: https://css-tricks.com/play-sound-on-hover/
2. If this whole thing is in separate div, the sound should play "whole" without any abrupt break. Correct me if I'm wrong
3. Now the thing probably the most difficult: how to make sure the animation doesn't show always when visiting main page. Setting a cookie? If so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can play sound using pure javascript, just get audio element and use play function on button click handler (example below):

```
`object.onclick = function(){
  document.getElementByTagName('audio')[0].play();
};`
```

2) The sound will play even if you hide this div.

3) You can set cookie using pure javascript:

```
`document.cookie = "name=value; path=/; expires=" + date.toUTCString();`
```

And then you can check if cookie exists using function below:

```
`function getCookie(name) {
  var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
    "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"
  ));
  return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
}`
```

If you're jquery guy, you can use https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/